# Python/Pandas/BigQuery: How to efficiently update existing tables with a lot of new time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have one program that downloads time series (ts) data from a remote database and saves the data as `csv` files. New ts data is appended to old ts data. My local folder continues to grow and grow and grow as more data is downloaded. After downloading new ts data and saving it, I want to upload it to a Google BigQuery table. What is the best way to do this?

My current work-flow is to download all of the data to `csv` files, then to convert the `csv` files to `gzip` files on my local machine and then to use `gsutil` to upload those `gzip` files to `Google Cloud Storage`. Next, I delete whatever tables are in `Google BigQuery` and then manually create a new table by first deleting any existing table in `Google BigQuery` and then creating a new one by uploading data from `Google Cloud Storage`. I feel like there is room for significant automation/improvement but I am a Google Cloud newbie.

Edit: Just to clarify, the data that I am downloading can be thought of downloading time series data from Yahoo Finance. With each new day, there is fresh data that I download and save to my local machine. I have to uploading all of the data that I have to `Google BigQUery` so that I can do `SQL` analysis on it.

Comment: Have you seen the [Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer/)? I wonder if that would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider breaking up your data into daily tables (or partitions). Then you only need to upload the CVS from the current day.

The script you have currently defined otherwise seems reasonable.

- Extract your new day of CSVs from your source of timeline data.
- Gzip them for fast transfer.
- Copy them to GCS.
- Load the new CVSs into the current daily table/partition.

This avoids the need to delete existing tables and reduces the amount of data and processing that you need to do. As a bonus, it is easier to backfill a single day if there is an error in processing.

Comment: I like this idea but what about when you decide to start tracking a new timeseries. Your first download of that time series would give you data across many days

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a great way to handle this case today, without a LOAD operation per-previous day. You might open a feature request on BigQuery's public issue tracker to better support this bulk-load case.